# 3D Point cloud road lines extraction

Tags: opencv, 3d, point-cloud-library, lidar

I have to detect road lines in lidar 3D point cloud data.  I am using point cloud library. I interactively select the co-ordinates of any 2 points on the the line and fit line passing through these 2 points to segment out all the points on the line.
[image: Straight road line detection] 
The above approach  work if road is straight. When road is curved, it fails.

Now I am trying different approaches. I am using conditional euclidean clustering class of pcl library. I cluster the all the points with road line intensity. The road boundary lines are yellow. I choose intensity threshold accordingly. The results are as shown in the below image. [image: Curved road line detection]

The blue points represents the road boundary lines. I want smoother line as similar to results obtained when road is straight. Please let me know what better approaches I can try to trace the road lines in 3d point cloud data.

Comment: Have you tried curve-fitting on the points marked by blue?

Comment: Thanks for reply, ultimately i am trying fit curve only. For straight line I use ransac model for line fitting, but for curve fitting i am not getting any exact algorithm.

Comment: Like @GarvitaTiwari suggested (and as used on OpenStreetMaps) you could try using small straight segments to approximate a curve. For every road segment, check if the stddev (or some other error) is more than a threshold, If so, break the line into 2 segments (naively in the middle) and refit the line. Repeat till smallest length is reached (say 2m). To reduce the number of segments, you could merge them with same criteria. Or during the breaking part, use an optimizer to break into as few parts to keep error within limits. See https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp/glop

Comment: Thanks Kunal, Its really helpful for me. I will follow you suggestions.